# Mute microphone while capturing video using intent on Android 6.0.1 or above

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-video-record

I want to capture a video on android 6.0 and also want that it will not record audio while capturing video. I tried to mute microphone programmatically but it is not working on Android 6.0 and above. Someone please share your experience to solve this problem any type of help will be appreciated!
I used below code to mute microphone

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE);
        if (audioManager.isMicrophoneMute() == false) {
            audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(true);
        } else {
            audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(false);
        }
```

and for open camera using intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

        // set video quality
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.MEDIA_SCANNER_VOLUME, 0);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file

        // start the video capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can help while put mode in call

```
 AudioManager audioManager = ((AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE));
            audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
            if(state) //state-boolean
            {
               audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(false);
               audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
               state = false;
            }
            else
            {
              audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(true);
              state = true;
            }
```

Comment: I checked in my phone (Redmi Note 4 )with Nougat it may help.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
private void setMicMuted(boolean state){
AudioManager myAudioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

// get the working mode and keep it
int workingAudioMode = myAudioManager.getMode();

myAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

// change mic state only if needed
if (myAudioManager.isMicrophoneMute() != state) {
    myAudioManager.setMicrophoneMute(state);
}

// set back the original working mode
myAudioManager.setMode(workingAudioMode);
```

}